# How to compile LESS pager?

Tags: compiling, less

I would like to compile `less` with latest fixes.

I do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/gwsw/less
cd less/
autoheader
autoconf
./configure
make
```

But `make` says this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'funcs.h', needed by 'main.o'. Stop.
```

There are no Makefile rules that create `funcs.h`

So, how to compile `less` from source?

Comment: Then what happened?

Comment: It seems running `make -f Makefile.aut funcs.h` before `make` fixes the problem. But I'm not sure if this sequence is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the method I just successfully used on Ubuntu 18.04:

- `git clone https://github.com/gwsw/less.git`
- `cd less`
- `autoreconf -i`  # install the `autoconf` package if you haven't already
- `make -f Makefile.aut dist`

This creates a directory `release/less-550` containing `less-550.tar.gz` and `less-550.zip`. It also attempts to create a gpg signature for `less-550.tar.gz`. That hung on my system, so I killed the `gpg --detach-sign ...` process from another window.  You could also just kill the `make` process.

`less-550.tar.gz` is a standard buildable source tarball, which you can install as usual:

- `tar xf less-550.tar.gz`
- `cd less-550`
- `./configure --prefix=`*some-directory* *other-options*
- `make`
- `make install`

The most interesting options for `./configure` are probably:

```
--with-regex=LIB        select regular expression library
                        (LIB is one of
                         auto,none,gnu,pcre,pcre2,posix,
                         regcmp,re_comp,regcomp,regcomp-local) [auto]
--with-editor=PROGRAM   use PROGRAM as the default editor [vi]
```

Run `./configure --help` for a full list of options.

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [Thomas Dickey’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468216/86440), the git repository needs preparation before it can be used to build, and one required file can’t be recreated using the provided files.

To build less, download [its latest release tarball](http://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html) and build that:

```
wget http://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/less-530.tar.gz
tar xf less-530.tar.gz
cd less-530
./configure && make
```

Note however that version 530 has [a few annoying bugs](http://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html) which are fixed in the git repository. (This could be why the Debian package hasn’t been updated.)

Alternatively, you can update the Debian package:

```
sudo apt build-dep less
sudo apt install devscripts
apt source less
cd less-487
uscan
cd ..
tar xf less_530.orig.tar.gz
cd less-530
cp -a ../less-487/debian .
dch -v 530-0.1 "New upstream release."
dch -r ignored
debuild -uc -uc
```

This will produce a `less_530-0.1_yourarch.deb` (where `yourarch` is probably `amd64`), which you can install using `sudo dpkg -i`. As [JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5132/jdebp) [points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468215/how-to-compile-less-pager/468218?noredirect=1#comment853334_468218), this will ensure that the Debian patches are applied, and that the appropriate `configure` options are used; it will also give you the benefits of using a package instead of a manual installation.

For `gbp` fans like myself, the following recipe uses a git repository which makes any changes more obvious:

```
sudo apt build-dep less
sudo apt install devscripts git-buildpackage
gbp import-dsc --pristine-tar apt://less/sid
cd less
gbp import-orig --pristine-tar --uscan
dch -v 530-0.1 "New upstream release."
dch -r ignored
gbp buildpackage -us -uc --git-ignore-new
```

(In both cases, strictly speaking you should use `dch -n` and `dch -v`, or at least add “Non-maintainer upload.” to the changelog, but that’s harder to do in a copy-pastable way.)

Answer (score 3):

***"Makefile.in"*** is an input to ***"configure"***, which generates **"Makefile"**. You need not specify "Makefile" in the make-command.  So this should work better:

```
./configure
make
```

(though you may have left files in that directory which should be removed before re-running configure).

Running from git, you're missing the **distribution** files such as **configure**.  If you have a suitable version of autoconf installed, you would have to prepare the build by first running

```
autoconf
```

However, the git tree also omits "defines.h.in" — more preparation is needed: none of the files in git appears to match the needed template.  You **might** be able to reuse the corresponding file from a release tar-ball, though that's unreliable (like any other source-file, it changes).  Since the documentation doesn't mention this step, a bug report to the developer might help.

The revised question asks about **`funcs.h`**, which can be created using the rule in **`Makefile.aut`** (*"Makefile for authoring less"*, according to the comment at the top of the file).  But as of 2018/09/17, there still is no rule to create **`defines.h.in`** (use grep to answer these questions).

Comment: I've sent bug report.

Comment: Running `autoheader` before `autoconf` seems to help. But `make` says `make: *** No rule to make target 'funcs.h', needed by 'main.o'.  Stop.` ...

Comment: There's a makefile rule for creating that file (the makefile doesn't have dependencies telling it to make the file before trying to compile).

Comment: There are no Makefile targets that create `funcs.h`.

Comment: Take a look in `Makefile.aut` (grep helps).

Answer (score 0):

This sequence does the job, but I'm not sure that it is correct:

```
git clone https://github.com/gwsw/less
cd less/
autoheader
autoconf
./configure
make -f Makefile.aut funcs.h
make
make -f Makefile.aut less.nro
make -f Makefile.aut lesskey.nro
make -f Makefile.aut lessecho.nro
make install
```